# Why fetch() exceeds maximum call stack?

Tags: javascript, redux-thunk

That's actually a code from [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) examples:

```
function fetchSecretSauce() {
  return fetch('https://www.google.com/search?q=secret+sauce');
}
```

Here's what I'm working with:

```js
const fetch = () => {
     return fetch('https://www.google.com/search?q=secret+sauce')
    }
    
    console.log(fetch())
```

If you "Run code snippet", you'll get the error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I've also tried different links.

Comment: No-repo from just the code you've quoted. Perhaps they've redefined `fetch` in their code in a way that conflicts with the new standard.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with `fetchSecretSauce()`? How are you logging the result?

Comment: @JeremyBanks fixed.

Comment: So you're declaring a function called `fetch` that calls a function called `fetch`...?

Answer (score 3):

Your fiddle is incorrect and doesn't represent the example you provided from [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk). In their example, they wrap a `fetch` request with a function called `fetchSecretSauce`. What you've done is declared a function `fetch` which calls a function `fetch` (the function you just defined), thus creating an infinite loop by calling itself over and over.

The JavaScript engine has a limit to the amount of times something can be called. When this limit is hit, the JavaScript engine thinks like so:

> I believe this is going to go on forever, so I'll prevent anything bad
>   from happening and terminate it now. I'll also give you this descriptive
>   message: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Below you'll find an example which is the same exact as yours minus the function name. Hit "Run code snippet" and you'll see the same infinite loop:

```js
function infiniteLoop() {
  return infiniteLoop('https://www.google.com/search?q=secret+sauce');
}

console.log(foo());
```

Do exactly as they do in their example and **rename** the wrapper function something entirely different. Name it whatever you want, just **don't** name it `fetch`.

```
function searchGoogleForSecretSauce() {
  return fetch('https://www.google.com/search?q=secret+sauce');
}
```